# view rendering from json using angular ngFor

Tags: angular, typescript

Below data should be logically translated into list items.

So the final output is expected like below,

```
<ul>
    <li>Unordered Item One</li>
    <li>Unordered Item Two</li>
    <li>Unordered Item three</li>
    <li> 
        <ol>
            <li>Ordered Item A</li>
            <li>Ordered Item B</li>
        </ol>
    </li>   
</ul>
```

I've created `recursion` component to render all these items,

In Recursion Component,

```
<ng-container *ngIf="nested.type==='list-item'">
  <li>{{text}}</li>
</ng-container>
```

But it doesn't render the child items, Please show me what I'm doing wrong here.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn' t work because you are not having any input property as `nested` in the recursion component. IMHO, you don't need as many input properties just each Child object will do.

Have something like:

App componenent

```
<ng-container *ngIf="nested.type==='unordered-list-item'">
    <li>{{nested.text}}</li>
    <ul *ngIf="nested.children.length > 0">
        <app-recursion *ngFor="let child of nested.children" [child]="child"></app-recursion>
    </ul>
</ng-container>
```

Recursion Component.

```
<ng-container *ngIf="child?.type==='unordered-list-item'">
  <li>{{child.text}}</li>
  <ng-container *ngIf="child.children?.length > 0">
    <ul>
            <app-recursion *ngFor="let subChild of child.children" [child]="subChild"></app-recursion>
    </ul>
  </ng-container>
</ng-container>

<ng-container *ngIf="child?.type==='ordered-list-item'">
  <li>{{child.text}}</li>
  <ng-container *ngIf="child.children?.length > 0">
    <ol>
            <app-recursion *ngFor="let subChild of child.children" [child]="subChild"></app-recursion>
    </ol>
  </ng-container>
</ng-container>
```

See an example here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qzezhp?file=src%2Fapp%2Frecursion%2Frecursion.component.html

**EDIT**

With the current logic, list type is being decided by the parent, for example, if the last child in the root has type: "ordered-list-item" and its children are of type `unordred-list-item` then still ordered lists are generated with something like:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="child?.type==='ordered-list-item'">
  <li>{{child.text}}</li>
  <ng-container *ngIf="child.children?.length > 0">
    <ol>  <-- even though children are un-ordered
            <app-recursion *ngFor="let subChild of child.children" [child]="subChild"></app-recursion>
    </ol>
  </ng-container>
</ng-container>
```

Solution:

Have another property in each object which tells about the children type, I have named that property as `childrenType` and used with a dummy data, you will jhave to write your logic to add this property dynamically.

Once this has been done:

You can have something like this in your Recursion component.

```
  <li>{{child.text}}</li>
    <ng-container *ngIf="child.children?.length > 0">
        <ul *ngIf="child.childrenType==='unordered-list-item'">
            <app-recursion *ngFor="let subChild of child.children" [child]="subChild"></app-recursion>
        </ul>
    <ol *ngIf="child.childrenType==='ordered-list-item'">
      <app-recursion *ngFor="let subChild of child.children" [child]="subChild"></app-recursion>
    </ol>
    </ng-container>
```

See a revised example here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-list-component-4kmets?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: It as an issue, if it is `unordered-list-item` it still shows as `orderered-list-item` https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-list-component?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

change or remove condition in recursion component: ***ngIf="nested.type==='unordered-list-item'"**

```
  <ng-container>
      <li>{{text}}</li>
    </ng-container>
```

Comment: But, `ordered-list-item` is not rendering

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that the type of inner children is ordered (not unordered).
So, just change the Recursion Component to :

```
<ng-container *ngIf="nested.type==='ordered-list-item'">
<li>{{text}}</li>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: But, ordered-list-item is not rendering

Comment: I do not understand what you mean. You place a condition that does not exist and therefore the data is not displayed. You must change or cancel the condition

Answer (score 0):

Send data into your `app-recursion` component from `nested.children` array.

So `app.component.html` should look like this:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="nested.type==='unordered-list-item'">
    <li>{{nested.text}}</li>    
    <ul *ngIf="nested.children.length > 0">     
    <app-recursion [children]="nested.children"></app-recursion>
    </ul>
</ng-container>
```

And then use `*ngFor` in `recursion.component.html`:

```
<ng-container >
  <li *ngFor="let child of children" >
      {{child.text}}
  </li>
</ng-container>
```